# get number of times values on the basis of input value

Tags: sql

Input table

```
Col
1
2
2
3
3
4
5
```

Output

```
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
5
5
5
5
5
```

Is there any way this could be achieved in sql with and without writing any function ? Please take a note that, column can have duplicate values.

Comment: Why are there four 2's but six 3's in the expected output?

Comment: because first 2 will produce 2 outputs and 2nd 2 will do the same thing, and for 1st three there will be 3 times 3 in out and for 2nd 3 too..will do the same

Comment: What DBMS are you using? You should always tag SQL requests with the DBMS they relate to.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a cross join to a *numbers/tally* table. You already have one in your source data, so you can simply use it as a distinct list:

```
select i.col
from input i
cross join (select distinct col as n from input) n
where n.n <= i.col
order by i.col
```

Answer (score 1):

you didn't state your DBMS product, but in Postgres this can be done using `generate_series()

```
select t.col
from the_table t
  cross join generate_series(1, t.col) 
order by t.col
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a standard SQL recursive query for this:

```
with cte (num, cnt) as
(
  select num, num from mytable
  union all
  select num, cnt - 1 from cte where cnt > 1
)
select num from cte order by num;
```